# How to change configuration of log4j in runtime

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a command line application in which I have enabled log4j. For now only file logging is added. Now I want that, without restarting or recompiling jar file I should be able to change configuration of log4j.

I read in log4j manual that it can automatically detect changes in config file. So how can I put config file in some separate location and have it's changes reflected in runtime in the application?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. They are covered in the log4j [configuration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

The simplest is to put a log4j.xml on the classpath. Then add the monitorInterval="30" attribute to the opening configuration tag. This tells log4j to check the file for changes every 30 seconds.

Comment: yes, but for this approach, I will have to recompile jar and redeploy right? I don't want to do that. How to make log4j accept external configuration file?

Comment: yes, I have. I am searching for a way of using properties file (external). So that any changes to it will reflect in the app at runtime

Comment: Are you asking how to put a file on the classpath in the file system?

Comment: No, if I put config file in classpath, everytime I change it I will have to rebuild jar and redeply it, right? Please correct me if I am wrong as I am fairly new to java. So I want a way to use .properties file and have it checked in regular intervals so that if I make changes in it, they are used automatically without having to stop the applicaton

Comment: A directory or file in the filesystem can be on the classpath. Changing something there does not require rebuilding/redeploying jars/wars. It is not clear to me if one can make log4j monitor a .properties file or just the .xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the system property 'log4j.configuration' to specify the config file location.

.. -Dlog4j.configuration="path.to.my.config.xml"